# Voltage boosting device for electrostatic experiment

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, electrostatic

I want to get 2kV to 6kV (adjustable) for performing electrostatic experiments with parallel plates.
What device can produce such high voltages from the 230V mains?

I watched a [video](https://youtu.be/zE50c7t4Bmo) on YouTube experimenting with electrostatics. They had used a device which looks similar to a bench power supply to step up the voltage to 6kV.

It looked like this:

[image]

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic for this site and I don't think you ought to build one unless you can demonstrate the skills because they can be ruthlessly dangerous.

Comment: @Andyaka Asking the name of an electric device is a shopping question?? I'm just asking the name of a device and not asking where I can find one. Does that still qualify as a shopping question??

Comment: OK, how about looking for a high voltage power supply using google? Such as this one: https://www.lambdaphoto.co.uk/ps350-high-voltage-power-supply.html?keyword=&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_ez2BRCyARIsAJfg-kts5pZ_ynnwCJC3r_yCcwNbSZZ1kYg9EBnKnGXm4SfkeIhZ_Fswq6saAktMEALw_wcB

Answer (score 1):

That is a high voltage bench power supply,

Amateurs combine Variacs, neon sign transofrmers and rectifiers to make their own adjustable high voltage sources.

Those with a death wish use microwave oven transformers instead.